# lapply-ing with the "$" function

Tags: r, lapply

I was going through [some examples](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Functionals#exercises-1) in hadley's guide to functionals, and came across an unexpected problem.

Suppose I have a list of model objects,

```
x=1:3;y=3:1; bah <- list(lm(x~y),lm(y~x))
```

and want to extract something from each (as suggested in hadley's question about a list called "trials"). I was expecting one of these to work:

```
lapply(bah,`$`,i='call') # or...
lapply(bah,`$`,call)
```

However, these return nulls. It seems like I'm not misusing the `$` function, as these things work:

```
`$`(bah[[1]],i='call')
`$`(bah[[1]],call)
```

Anyway, I'm just doing this as an exercise and am curious where my mistake is. I know I could use an anonymous function, but think there must be a way to use syntax similar to my initial non-solution. I've looked through the places `$` is mentioned in `?Extract`, but didn't see any obvious explanation.

I just realized that this works:

```
lapply(bah,`[[`,i='call')
```

and this

```
lapply(bah,function(x)`$`(x,call))
```

Maybe this just comes down to some `lapply` voodoo that demands anonymous functions where none should be needed? I feel like I've heard that somewhere on SO before.

Comment: No voodoo. The "$" function does not evaluate its arguments, whereas "[[" does.

Comment: @DWin - can you please expound, I don't understand what you mean by that

Comment: @Dwin Maybe this is just over my head, but I'm not clear on what evaluation means here. It seems to evaluate args okay when called directly, as in `\`$\`(bah[[1]],i='call')`...? (argh: escaping inline backticks is annoying)

Comment: You can do either `ll[[varname]]` or `ll[['varname']]` and they mean different things. The first looks up the value of `varname`. With `$` you only get the second option, since it will never "reach out" and evaluate what character value `varname` might have had in the enclosing environment.

Comment: @DWin wouldn't `lapply(bah, \`$\`, 'call')` work then?

Comment: Not sure why `lapply(bah, `$`, 'call')` fails. I was surprised that `\`$\`(bah[[1]],call)` worked. Was expecting the same error that I get with: `lapply(bah, "[[", call)` stemming from the fact that `call` is a language function.

Comment: the impression I'm getting is that the `lapply` results in calls like this: `\`$\`(bah[[1]], )`, but I don't understand why

Comment: @eddi: the "Note" in the Details seciton of `?lapply` looks on point for that question.

Comment: My apologies for some of these comments that I now see as tangential. Would be more than happy to delete them, but didn't want to leave the responses dangling if the authors wanted to leave them up.

Comment: @DWin Ah, okay. That answers the question, I think. $ is a primitive, so lapply misbehaves. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented in `?lapply`, in the "Note" section (emphasis mine):

> For historical reasons, the calls created by `lapply` are unevaluated,
>   and code has been written (e.g. `bquote`) that relies on this.  This
>   means that the recorded call is always of the form `FUN(X[[0L]],
>   ...)`, with `0L` replaced by the current integer index.  This is not
>   normally a problem, but it can be if `FUN` uses `sys.call` or
>   `match.call` or **if it is a primitive function that makes use of the
>   call.**  This means that it is often safer to call primitive functions
>   with a wrapper, so that e.g. `lapply(ll, function(x) is.numeric(x))`
>   is required in R 2.7.1 to ensure that method dispatch for `is.numeric`
>   occurs correctly.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused - what call for the `$`-function does this `lapply(bah, \`$\`, 'call')` result in? It's apparently not `\`$\`(bah[[1L]], 'call')` which is how I seem to be reading that note (if you replace `...` with `'call'` and `FUN` with `\`$\``).

Comment: `\`$\`(bah[[1L]], ...)`