# How to pull values out of a list based on a vector of list indices in R

Tags: r, list

Dummy example:

```
1> L = vector('list',100)#prefill empty list
1> for (i in 1:100){
1+ L[[i]]$letter = letters[rgeom(1,.5)+1]#populate it with a letter
1+ L[[i]]$number = runif(1)#and a number
1+ }
1> i = ceiling(runif(100,0,100))#an (arbitrary) vector of indices
1> x = L[[i]]$letter #I want the ith letter
Error in L[[i]] : no such index at level 2
```

I want `x` to contain the `letter` object of the `i`th element of `L`.  (the order of `i` doesn't have anything to do with the index order of `x`)

What is a good way to do this without a loop?

Here is copy/paste from my editor, instead of my terminal window, for those who may find it easier:

```
L = vector('list',100)
for (i in 1:100){
    L[[i]]$letter = letters[rgeom(1,.5)+1]
    L[[i]]$number = runif(1)
}
i = ceiling(runif(100,0,100))
x = L[[i]]$letter
```

Comment: Your `1>` and `+` at the start of lines makes it a pain to copy-paste and try your code

Comment: @Frank how's that for you?

Comment: Sure, thanks. The problem seems to be: `i` is a vector, not a number while `[[]]` only takes a single number. If you want to grab the `letter` for each of those numbers, `sapply(L[i], \`[[\`, "letter")` should work. Not sure if that's what you're after.

Comment: Indeed it is.  You want to make that an answer and explain why quoting a couple of brakets makes any sense, and I'll totally accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant documentation is at `help("[[")`:

> The most important distinction between `[`, `[[` and `$` is that the `[` can select more than one element whereas the other two select a single element.

So, we need to pull values out with `L[i]`.

From there, to access the `$letter` part of each of the elements of `L[i]`, we can use `sapply`:

```
sapply(L[i], `[[`, "letter")
```

It's tempting to use `$` instead of `[[` here, but [for obscure reasons, it's not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18216084/1191259).

---

*Comment.* Here's an alternative way of building some example data.

```
set.seed(1)
L = replicate(100, list(
  letter = letters[rgeom(1,.5)+1], 
  number = runif(1)
), simplify = FALSE)
i = sample(100, 100, replace=TRUE)
```

It's often useful to put a `set.seed` ahead of a randomly-generated example so everyone's looking at the same thing.