# How to lapply `$` to a list

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of lists, each sublist has dozens of elements and I just want to extract one of them.

```
x = list(`1` = list(a=1,b=2),`2` = list(a=3,b=4))
```

There are many ways to accomplish this, but I want to be as clever as possible so I try

```
lapply(x,`$`,"b")
# $`1`
# NULL
# 
# $`2`
# NULL
```

but this doesn't work despite the fact that

```
`$`(x[[1]],"b")
# [1] 2
```

`mapply` does work like this:

```
mapply(`$`,x,MoreArgs=list(name="b"))
# 1 2 
# 2 4
```

I can use `lapply` like this:

```
 lapply(x,getElement,"b")
 # $`1`
 # [1] 2
 # 
 # $`2`
 # [1] 4
```

But why doesn't `lapply` work with `$` the way it ought to?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18216084/1191259

Comment: Thanks @Frank - I saw that before I posted but that's about `lapply`-ing on a subset of the parent list where I want to subset the child lists.

Comment: As the guy who wrote it, I don't know what you mean about subsets, but that's okay.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

`lapply(x,'[[',"b")`

```
$`1`
[1] 2

$`2`
[1] 4
```

Comment: That's good, but one character more than I want :)

Comment: @Mark `z <- \`[[\`; lapply(x,z,"b")`

Comment: @Frank why doesn't `z = '$'; lapply(x,z,"b")` work?

Comment: @Mark Because `lapply` is weird and fragile, I guess.