# Extraction operator `$`() returns zero-length vectors within function

Tags: r, function, scoping

I am encountering an issue when I use the extraction operator `$() inside of a function.  The problem does not exist if I follow the same logic outside of the loop, so I assume there might be a scoping issue that I'm unaware of.

The general setup:

```
## Make some fake data for your reproducible needs.
set.seed(2345)

my_df <- data.frame(cat_1 = sample(c("a", "b"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                    cat_2 = sample(c("c", "d"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                    continuous  = rnorm(100),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(my_df)
```

This process I am trying to dynamically reproduce:

```
index <- which(`$`(my_df, "cat_1") == "a")

my_df$continuous[index]
```

But once I program this logic into a function, it fails:

```
## Function should take a string for the following:
##  cat_var - string with the categorical variable name as it appears in df
##  level - a level of cat_var appearing in df
##  df - data frame to operate on.  Function assumes it has a column 
##    "continuous".
extract_sample <- function(cat_var, level, df = my_df) {

  index <- which(`$`(df, cat_var) == level)

  df$continuous[index]

}

## Does not work.
extract_sample(cat_var = "cat_1", level = "a")
```

This is returning `numeric(0)`.  Any thoughts on what I'm missing?  Alternative approaches are welcome as well.

Comment: Fwiw, I would do `extract_sample = function(var, val, df = my_df) merge(df, setNames(data.frame(val), var), all.y=TRUE)` or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't the function, it's the way `$` handles the input.

```
cat_var = "cat_1"
length(`$`(my_df,"cat_1"))
#> [1] 100
length(`$`(my_df,cat_var))
#> [1] 0
```

You can instead use `[[` to achieve your desired outcome.

```
cat_var = "cat_1"
length(`[[`(my_df,"cat_1"))
#> [1] 100
length(`[[`(my_df,cat_var))
#> [1] 100
```

**UPDATE**

It's been noted that using `[[` this way is ugly. And it is. It's useful when you want to write something like `lapply(stuff,'[[',1)`

Here, you should probably be writing it as `my_df[[cat_var]]`.

Also, [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216084/lapply-ing-with-the-function) goes into a little more detail about why `$` doesn't work the way you want it to.

Comment: What's ugly? The way R handles it or my example?

Comment: @HongOoi I share your aesthetic judgement, but perhaps it could be expressed differently? ;) I think the point here is that we should probably be using `[[` with it's usual semantics: `my_df[[cat_var]]`.

Comment: The main reason to be doing it this way is to support the `apply` family

Comment: I think maybe it was a little confusing because the OP didn't really need to use `[[` in that sort of anonymous function passed to `lapply` context, that's all.

Comment: Thanks guys, the ``[[`` operator is exactly what I was forgetting.  This simplifies things quite a bit.

Comment: Fair, I was just trying to imitate the style they were using. Updated the answer to show the more visually pleasing form.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `$` is non-standard, in the sense that when you don't quote the parameter input, it still tries to parse it and use what you typed, even if that was meant to refer to another variable.

Or more simply, as @42 put it in the first comment in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18216084/210673):

> The "$" function does not evaluate its arguments, whereas "[[" does`.

Here's a much simpler data set as an example.

```
my_df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2))
v <- "a"
```

Compare the usual usage; the first two give the same result, if you don't quote it, it parses it.  So the third one (now) clearly doesn't work properly.

```
my_df$"a"
## [1] 1 2

my_df$a
## [1] 1 2

my_df$v
## NULL
```

That's exactly what's happening to you:

```
`$`(my_df, "a")
## [1] 1 2

`$`(my_df, v)
## NULL
```

Instead we need to evaluate `v` before sending to `$` by using `do.call`.

```
do.call(`$`, list(my_df, v))
## [1] 1 2
```

Or, more appropriately, use the `[[` version which does evaluate the parameters first.

```
`[[`(my_df, v)
## [1] 1 2
```

Comment: Besides that link, there's also https://stackoverflow.com/a/18228613/ which quotes the source code for the "not evaluated" point.

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies in the way you are indexing to the column. This works just making a slight tweak to yours:

```
extract_sample <- function(cat_var, level, df = my_df) {
  index <- df[, cat_var] == level
  df$continuous[index]
}
```

Using it dynamically:

```
> extract_sample(cat_var = "cat_2", level = "d")
 [1] -0.42769207 -0.75650031  0.64077840 -1.02986889  1.34800344  0.70258431  1.25193247
 [8] -0.62892048  0.48822673  0.10432070  1.11986063 -0.88222370  0.39158408  1.39553002
[15] -0.51464283 -1.05265106  0.58391650  0.10555913  0.16277385 -0.55387829 -1.07822831
[22] -1.23894422 -2.32291394  0.11118881  0.34410388  0.07097271  1.00036812 -2.01981056
[29]  0.63417799 -0.53008375  1.16633422 -0.57130500  0.61614135  1.06768285  0.74182293
[36]  0.56538633  0.16784205 -0.14757303 -0.70928924 -1.91557732  0.61471302 -2.80741967
[43]  0.40552376 -1.88020372 -0.38821089 -0.42043745  1.87370600 -0.46198139  0.10788358
[50] -1.83945868 -0.11052531 -0.38743950  0.68110902 -1.48026285
```

Comment: Note that this will work with regular data frames, but if you use tidyverse functions that return tibbles, `df[, x]` will return a 1-column tibble. Best to use `df[[x]]` instead, which works with everything.

Comment: Or just not use tidyverse ;) (thanks and it's a good point to bear in mind)